# How automatically press Ctrl+Z in C

Tags: key, ctrl

I want to make a program that automatically press `Ctrl+Z` and then release them. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Here is a piece of my code that I want to press automatically `Ctrl+Z`:

```
if (name[NumOfChars-1]=='\n'){
    name[NumOfChars-1]='&';
    if (name[NumOfChars-1]=='&'){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On what platform? If it's Unix, then fetch your own pid and send the SIGTSTP signal to it.